# correct use and design of gated clock in Verilog

Tags: verilog, timing

I have a design I am working on in Verilog. In part of my design a counter is incremented by a clock - this occurs a half clock cycle before the output of the counter is latched into a parallel load shift register.

In some circumstances I want to HOLD the counter. To do this I have gated the clock:

```
assign sync_gated = i_sync || !r_en;
```

This is combinational logic, but I don't see any issue as there is a full clock cycle (we run at 2MHz) for the output of the counter to settle. A few ns of propagation delay will not cause a problem.

The code synthesises OK,  but I get this warning:

> y_ctr/sync_gated_inv(y_ctr/sync_gated_inv1:O)|
>   NONE(*)(y_ctr/r_axis_address_15)| 16    |
>   x_ctr/sync_gated_inv(x_ctr/sync_gated_inv1:O)|
>   NONE(*)(x_ctr/r_axis_address_15)| 16    |
>   ---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------+ (*) These 2 clock signal(s) are generated by combinatorial logic, and
>   XST is not able to identify which are the primary clock signals.
>   Please use the CLOCK_SIGNAL constraint to specify the clock signal(s)
>   generated by combinatorial logic

Is this bad design? if so, why? or do I just need to add some constraint here to reassure the compiler?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'just' gate the clock. You can get all kind of clocking artifacts. 
Look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/352464/what-does-it-mean-to-gate-the-clock/352470#352470) for how to gate a clock.